# Curried generic placement

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

What is the exact difference between these two:

`type X1 = <A, B extends A>(a: A) => (b: B) => void`

and

`type X2 = <A>(a: A) => <B extends A>(b: B) => void`

Comment: The first is a generic function that returns a non generic function. The second is a generic function that returns a generic function.

Comment: does it make any difference in practice though?

Comment: It makes a significant difference because the the generic the type arguments for each generic type parameter are resolved when the function is called.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the function is called"? There are no types at runtime :)

Comment: That's correct. What I meant was at the call site. In other words at the point, lexically, where the function is called in the source code

Comment: Ok I understand what you are saying, but when I look at [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgjFAvFAPAQQDRQEJQgD2AgDsATAZyjQD4AKAQwC4qBKJaqWgI2ezcQ4A3APYBLUgFgAUKEiwATElQ0GzNPw4pcBImUoqeODVBHjp0gMbDi5YFC4AbenGbwlxAK4OHUepXrEIJbWtvZO8q6KyJ7evv6B5lJWNnYAThDkCMiOzrRwbAD0BVDJoemZzNzMngC2XBCpxqaSSSFpGVFh9PJ5hcWl7eQRqNqEJBRQtfWpdIZ87CZipEA) then the difference seems only syntactic sugar, doesn't it? Or is there some better example to illustrate the difference?

Comment: See whet happens to the types when you call the function function https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgjFAvFAPAQQDRQEJQgD2AgDsATAZyjQD4AKAQwC4qBKJaqWgI2ezcQ4A3APYBLUgFgAUKEiwATElQ0GzNPw4pcBImUoqeODVBHjp0gMbDi5YFC4AbenGbwlxAK4OHUepXrEIJbWtvZO8q6KyJ7evv6B5lJWNnYAThDkCMiOzrRwLLQAzGwA9CVQyaHpmczczJ4AtlwQqcamkkkhaRlRYfTyeQXFUGUVXVDVEajahCQUUI3NqXSGfOwmYqRAA notice how the type of `b` is different